# What would explain why modern civilation hasn't evolved much after 200 years?

Tags: future

For example the year 2019.

Why would the world be relatively the same technologically after 200 years?

Comment: Please considering fleshing out your question with more details and making it more specific to avoid having it closed for being too broad. 

For instance do you mean if technology stopped at 1819 and never progressed for 200 years? 

Or do you men starting today, technology stagnated for two centuries?

Comment: Why do you believe that civilization and  technology are the same thing? Some people may argue that while human technology has made great progress since the late 19th century, the progress of human *civilization* has been very much slower, or maybe even non-existent.

Comment: Maybe it's just a lousy or corrupt society.

Comment: that pretty much impossible, modern civilization relies on a great number of resources that will not last 200 years without a drastic change in how we use them.

Answer (score 4):

**The world is a simulation.**

In the Matrix, humanity was stuck in 1999, the year the Matrix went up.  In actuality several centuries had passed with the real humanity living in tubs of mucus.

I am not sure if in the Matrix they kept the same Top 40 songs month to month because if they did people might catch on.  Unless they were really good songs.

Answer (score 2):

**A planet-scale cataclysm**

A sickness, a major volcan eruption or a nuclear winter has wiped out the majority of the human poblation in 2020, and after 200 years mankind is finally recovering and rebuilding, with roughly the same tech available in 2020.

A good example of this is [The 100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_100_(TV_series)). Mankind had been forced into exile (in a space station orbiting Earth) and after a few generations they come back to Earth with essentially the same technology they had years back.